# jQuery replace span content by string

Tags: jquery, typescript

I have a string containing html markup in following format:

```
<p>
  <span class="xyz-display">
    <lots of other contents>
  </span>
</p>
```

I need to replace everything inside `<span class="xyz-display">` by a string before running sanitation on the string. So it looks like below:

```
<p>
  <span class="xyz-display">
    abc
  </span>
</p>
```

After this I need to replace `abc` by the original content `<lots of other contents>` back. How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: $(".xyz-display").text("your_content");

Answer (score 0):

Try this to change the contents of the `<span>` tag:

```
$("span.xyz.display").html("<lots of other contents>")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('span')
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    a[i].whatever="" // to change and use the same method to change it back`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a demo with a button. Main concept here is

```
$(".xyz-class > span").html(what_to_add);
```

What it actually does is takes the instance of xyz-class. Further ">" represents the child element which is span element and html(what_to_add) is used to apply the HTML code to that section.

Here's a code for that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello world</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function add(){
            var what_to_add = '<p>Enter name </p> <input type="text" /> ';
            $(".xyz-class > span").html(what_to_add);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p class="xyz-class">
            <span>Hello world</span>
        </p>
        <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To add string you can assign what_to_add to some string you need. ie what_to_add ="Your string."
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $('.xyz-display').html('Hello! ')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="xyz-display">
  abc
</span>
```

try this one.